# Braintree sandbox transaction.sale gives error: "Sale Customer ID has already been taken"

Tags: meteor, payment, sandbox, braintree, nonce

I am trying out Braintree in sandbox mode using the Drop-in feature. 
I am creating a Client token using an existing `customerID`. But when I make `transaction.sale` call with this `customerId` and the option `storeInVault = true` it gives error the following error:

> Sale Customer ID has already been taken.

As per the documentation it should update the customer with the payment nonce.

Here is the code:

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: '10.00',
  paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, // Generated nonce passed from client
  customer: {
    id: 232057823,  //this customer exist in the vault
    email : user.emails[0].address
  },
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true,
    storeInVault: true 
    //storeInVaultOnSuccess: true 
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    if (result.success) {
         return result.success;
    } else {
            console.log('ERR Sale '+result.message);
            return result.success;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm using Meteor with the package `patrickml:braintree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look to be using the [Braintree Transaction Sale API Call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/), in which you have included the storeInVault: true option.  What this is doing is creating a transaction with the included payment method nonce and attempting to create a customer id of 232057823, which is why you are encountering that error.

If your goal is to simply update an existing customer, you'd want to use the [Customer Update API call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/update/).

Comment: I think that is what I may have to do . However as per the documentation : ** Existing customer with new payment method**
To associate this transaction's payment method with an existing customer, pass a customerId along with options.storeInVault or options.storeInVaultOnSuccess as true.

Node.js
`gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
  customerId: "theCustomerId",
  options: {
    storeInVaultOnSuccess: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {
});`

Comment: The documentation is correct, but I can see the confusion.  You are nesting the 'id' attribute within the customer options.  In the example you have linked, the customerId attribute is specified at the top level.

Comment: Aha the Eureka moment!!! Good catch , it always helps to have a second pair of eyes!.  Thanks a lot.